# Is "ZC + Reflection" equivalent to ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

By *reflection* I mean the schema:

if $\phi$ is a sentence, and if $\phi^{V_\alpha}$ is the formula obtained by merely bounding every quantifier in $\phi$ by $V_\alpha$, then: $$\phi \implies\exists \alpha \exists V_\alpha \ ( \phi^{V_\alpha})$$

Where as usual $V_\alpha$ is defined as: $$x=V_\alpha \iff \exists f: \\function(f) \land \\ dom(f)=\alpha \land \\ \forall \beta \in \alpha ( f(\beta ) = \bigcup \{P(f(\lambda)): \lambda < \beta\}) \land \\ x= \bigcup rng(f) $$

By *parametric reflection* it's meant:

if $\phi$ is a formula whose free variables are among $y_1,…,y_n,z_1,…,z_m,w$, then:

$for \ \ m,n=1,2,3,...\\ \forall y_1,...,y_n \exists \alpha \exists V_\alpha ( y_1,...,y_n \in V_\alpha \land \\ \forall z_1,..,z_m \in V_\alpha [\exists w (\phi) \to \exists w \in V_\alpha (\phi^{V_\alpha})])$

> Is "ZC + reflection" equivalent to ZFC?
>
> Is "ZC + parametric reflection" equivalent to ZFC?

Comment: Do you allow parameters in $\phi$?

Comment: $\phi$ is a *sentence* so it cannot have free variables.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Noah wrote, when set theorists talk about Reflection, they don't mean just sentences. They mean that every formula with parameters reflects. I don't see an immediate argument why this is stronger than Reflection for sentences only, but it feels like it should be stronger.

Comment: @Noah: This can't be the proof, since $V_\theta$ when $\theta$ is a $\beth$ fixed point will have reflected this, but for the least fixed point is not going to satisfy Reflection. No, the point is that Replacement follows from Reflection by finding a large enough $V_\alpha$ that contains all the images, then Reflection makes it into a formula that we can apply Separation to (in fact a bounded formula!).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah duh, silly moment.

Comment: I think if we are bothering to mention $x$ at all, then all $\phi^{V_\alpha}$ should really be $\phi^x$. My advice, on the other hand, would be to leave $x$ out of the whole thing. Do not clutter your formulas, you want people to read them. The extra layer of "formalism" does not really help.

Comment: By the way, the observation that reflection captures replacement is classical.

Comment: Yes, but there is no need to copy ugly writing. The fact that Harvey did it first does not change this. The point is that the extra layer of formalism is only needed when one is familiarizing oneself with these notions. When one is at a stage where a question such as this one can be even conceived, it does not help.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, the formula I wrote is along the way Harvey Friedman wrote it (with the except of $V_\alpha$ instead x is transitive), otherwise its the same formula.

Comment: Yes, so what? I'm giving you advice so your questions are better received.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, there is a misunderstanding here on my side, I read your comment wrong really, you said to leave $x$ out of the picture (I read it as $z$ really, anyhow). Yes I agree with that, I was also wondering about it, but I don't see it as a very big issue really, that's why I left it as it is. But Ok I'll refine it. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am assuming that the last line in the definition of $V_\alpha$,
$x=\bigcup \{(f(\lambda))\mid\lambda<\alpha\}$.)

ZC+"ℵ1 exists" proves the formula Con("ZC + reflection"). We will call an ordinal  sentence-determined if there is a   such that " is a sentence" holds,and  is the least ordinal such that " holds in " holds. Since there are uncountably many limit ordinals in ℵ1 and only countably many ordinals which are sentence-determined, there must be a limit ordinal  which is not sentence-determined. Then the formula ""ZC + reflection" holds in " must hold.

Comment: but wouldn't that mean that it is weaker than ZFC?

Comment: there must be something wrong here, because parametric reflection + ZC must be equivalent to ZFC, and so its consistency cannot be proved in ZFC, unless the $V_\alpha$'s are not transitive?

Comment: OK so you changed your old reply which was about parameteric reflection, while this is about sentence relation (which is called just *reflection* here).

Answer (score 1):

No your version of "reflection" does not imply full ZFC (not even consistency wise).

Suppose we live in a universe of ZFC+CH. There is a proper class of ordinals $\alpha$ (namely all limit ordinals $>\omega$) such that $V_\alpha$ satisfies ZC. On the other hand there are only (thanks to CH) $\omega_1$ many $\in$-theories. We thus can find $\alpha<\beta<\omega_2$ so that $V_\alpha$ and $V_\beta$ are elementarily equivalent and models of ZC. Clearly $V_\beta$ is a model of your version of "reflection", every instance is witnessed by $V_\alpha$ (note that $V_\alpha^{V_\beta}=V_\alpha$). However, from the point of view of $V_\beta$, $\omega_2$ does not exist (because $\beta<\omega_2$ and $V_\beta$ contains the true $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\omega))$ ) and thus it is not a model of ZFC.

I am sure the use of CH can be avoided.

Edit: To avoid CH, simply work in the minimal $V_\gamma$ that is a model of ZFC (if it exists) and find any elementarily equivalent $V_\alpha$ and $V_\beta$.

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but please see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680768/are-these-two-forms-of-parametric-reflection-equivalent-over-zermelo-set-theory and tell me why your argument here doesn't work for the second sort of reflection?

Comment: You're only using CH to get a set of $\in$-theories. How many do you think there are without CH? Proper class of them?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I used CH to make sure that there are such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that are below $\omega_2$

Comment: @Zuhair could you make your question more precise? What should or should work for that sort of "reflection"?

Comment: Okay, so you really just need a definable ordinal above $\beta$. Take the least pair of $\alpha<\beta$ such that $V_\alpha\equiv V_\beta$, and let $\kappa=\beta^+$. Your edit doesn't really work, since it relies on the existence of worldly cardinals.

Comment: I am not sure where you are going. One has to make sure that $V_\beta$ is not a model of ZFC. The first way was to find $\beta$ so that $\omega_2$ doesnt exists there. The edit was meant to be "work in $V_\gamma$ if it exists, otherwise in $V$", so that there are no $V_\beta$ whatsoever that are models of ZFC

Comment: @AndreasLietz, please see the link I referred you to. It contains two kinds of reflection, the first kind is the one mentioned here, its called reflection 1, the second kind is reflection 2. It's important to check that your argument must fail for reflection 2, otherwise its a false argument because reflection 2 is known to be as strong as ZF when added to Z.

Comment: @Zuhair Well there are several reasons, but mainly the argument above relies on the version of "reflection" here being parameter-free while the version in the link uses parameters. ($V_\alpha$ and $V_\beta$ being elementarily equivalent is only enough to make sure that $V_\alpha$ witnesses reflection inside $V_\beta$ for sentences).

Comment: @AndreasLietz, you are speaking about the sentence reflection here and not the parametric reflection *here*, OK, then.